# Lifecyle method flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Do we have **lifecycle** methods in flutter similar to the android activity lifecycle method?
Packages would work as well.
If yes then can someone please explain that?

Comment: If you mean widget lifecycle here an article about it: https://medium.flutterdevs.com/explore-widget-lifecycle-in-flutter-e36031c697d0

Comment: I meant complete app lifecycle like we have in Android onStart(), onPause(), onAttach(), onDetach()

Comment: This might be close: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class to emulate the same thing you want to do. The `WidgetsBindingObserver` has a method call `didChangeAppLifecycleState` that will triggered depending the app `AppLifecycleState`.

```
class LifecycleEventHandler extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  LifecycleEventHandler({this.resumeCallBack, this.detachedCallBack});

  final VoidCallback? resumeCallBack;
  final VoidCallback? detachedCallBack;

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        detachedCallBack!();
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        resumeCallBack!();
        break;
    }
    print('Observer');
  }
}
```

Comment: Applifecyle only supports 4 state inactive, paused, detached, resume... Let's say I want to provide some task to run in background will that be achievable?

Comment: Yes, you can set a different Isolate to run along with the main one.

Comment: What is isolate?

Comment: Check at this link: https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency